# How can I unpack binary data saved with Swift in python?

Tags: python, swift, binary, endianness

I have saved an array of doubles as a binary file as such

saving.swift

```
val items: [Double] = ...
if let outputStream = OutputStream(url: getFileUrl(), append: true) {
    outputStream.open()
    items.withUnsafeBytes {
        let byteArray: [UInt8] = Array($0)
        outputStream.write(byteArray, maxLength: byteArray.count)
    }
    outputStream.close()
}
```

I am trying to process those raw files with python now. How can I read those bytes back into a double array with python?

process.py
    import struct

```
f = open("data.bin", "rb")
try:
    byte = True
    while byte != "":
        byte_arr = f.read(8)
        print(byte_arr)
        print(len(byte_arr))
        U = struct.unpack("4H", byte_arr)
        print(U)
        # print(unpack_from(byte_arr))
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: What's wrong with using "d"?

Comment: Why are you using `4H`, which means "4 unsigned shorts", to read a double?

Comment: Meanwhile, what exactly do you mean by "array" here? If you want a list, you're probably going to want to `append` each value to that list. If you want an `array.array` or a NumPy array, you probably don't want to do any of this, and instead just the `fromfile` or similar function that does it for you.

Comment: This is a *bad* idea. `withUnsafeBytes` is *not* meant for serialization. For one, the resulting byte stream is endian-specific.

Comment: ‘d’ seems to be the solution. I didn’t read the docs carefully enough. Thanks.  Why is this necessarily a bad idea. I needed to create the absolute minimum byte size due to contraints of the device. What is the recommended approach?

Comment: @Alexander I was using withUnsafeBytes to minimize the file size on disk of a large number of doubles. Is there a suggested approach that would work better?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral I would investigate what binary serialization formats there are libraries for, for Swift. But I don't think using a more convoluted serialization format is a good choice, without first investigating file compression.